# jQuery sideToggle not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to use the jQuery sideToggle function for a functionality in my application.

The following is the code that I have.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectme">
    <option value=0>Select an Option</option>
    <option value=1>Select1</option>
    <option value=2>Select2</option>
</select>
<div class="clickme">Hello
    <div class="iamhidden">Hello once again</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".selectme").on("change",function(){
    if($(".selectme").val() == 1){
        click();
    }
    else if($(".selectme").val() == 2){
        click2();
    }
});

function click(){
    $(".clickme").on("click",function(){
        $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow");
    });
}
function click2(){
     $(".clickme").on("click",function(){
        $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow");
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.clickme{
    height: auto;
}
.iamhidden{
    display: none;
}
```

After I have selected one option and later select the other option and then click on the div "clickme", the sideToggle div shows itself for a while and then hides.

I'm new to jQuery and I do not know what is wrong with my code. I think that the onClick event that is being called twice in the code might have caused the problem but I cannot find a way out of this even after I tried many alternatives of renaming the div and so on.

JSFIDDLE link: http://jsfiddle.net/63dnapvd/

Can anyone please help me out in solving this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Every time you change the select, you add another event! You do not replace the click event, you append to a list of events to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you seem to have gotten confused about functions and calls and handlers. If you are using a handler, then it will activate whenever the event happens. so there is no need to wrap that inside a function, as calling the function itself would need another click.

you displayed your function twice, so it activated twice and toggled twice, causing it to go back up.

fixed here - http://jsfiddle.net/63dnapvd/2/

```
$(".clickme").on("click",function(){
    $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

edit - if you want a delay then it to go back up, then add a delay and call again. as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/63dnapvd/3/

```
 $(".clickme").on("click",function(){
    $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow").delay(200).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

EDIT 2:

if you need to do it when the div is clicked after a change then try this:

```
  $(".selectme").on("change",function(){ 

      /*Do whatever you needed to do on change here */

      $(".clickme").on("click",function(){
         $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow").delay(200).slideToggle("slow");
      });
  });
```

if you want to display the element after every change, try this:

```
  $(".selectme").on("change",function(){ 
         $(".iamhidden").slideToggle("slow").delay(200).slideToggle("slow");
  });
```

Comment: The functionality of my application requires me to put the slideToggle function when there is a change in the select option. I'm loading the divs content on change of the option and I want that to be inside that functions and not a generic one..

Comment: So its not a click handler you need then? its a change?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry. I understood how the event handlers in jquery work now! :) Thank you very much for the answer @LiamHT